# Custom adapter on a recycler view not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I created a ListView custom adapter, now I want to use a RecyclerView for horizontal scrolling. But it doesn't work! This is my adapter code:

```
public class blogAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<blogData> data;

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public ArrayList<blogData> orig;



    public blogAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<blogData> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        blogHolder holder = new blogHolder();
        View vi = convertView;

        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.blog_row, null);

        holder.button = vi.findViewById(R.id.buttonRowBlog);
        holder.button.setText(data.get(position).getMainText());
        holder.button.setTag(position);

        holder.imageV = vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewBlog);
        holder.imageV.setTag(position);
        holder.imageV.setImageResource(data.get(position).getImage());

        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int buttonId = data.get(position).getID();
                MainActivity.BlogForward(buttonId);
            }
        });

        return vi;
    }

}
```

...and right here when I tried to set the Adapter, it said i couldn't

```
        recView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyc);

        arrayList = new ArrayList<blogData>();
        arrayList.add(new blogData(R.drawable.star, "test0", 0));
        arrayList.add(new blogData(R.drawable.star, "test1", 1));
        arrayList.add(new blogData(R.drawable.star, "test2", 2));
        arrayList.add(new blogData(R.drawable.star, "test3", 3));


        adapter = new blogAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
        recView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I don't understand why it doesn't let me use that Adapter
"Required type: Adapter
Provided: blogAdapter"

Comment: Could you include your `BaseAdapter` as well?